# How go to the previous page with $location.search?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am replacing `$window.location` with `$location.search` to avoid to display loading indicators at every page transition.

I don't know how to replace the instruction below to go back to the previous page:

```
$window.history.go(-1);
```

Is there a variant for `$location` too?

Comment: use following <a href="#" onclick="window.history.back();return false;">Back</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, according to Angular doc:

> The $location service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on the window.location)

This would in no way make history available to the $location service, and is confirmed by the [$location API doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)